# Программная установка фокуса на input

Tags: javascript

Есть обычное текстовое поле и блок div.

Нужно при клике на блок, поставить курсор в тестовое поле, что бы сразу писать текст.

Что то не получается это сделать...

Пробовал так:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" onClick="document.getElementById('textbox').select(); document.getElementById('textbox').focus();">
</div>
```

Но не работает. Как это можно сделать на чистом js?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fJzs2/ все работает.

Comment: подтверждаю - работает

Comment: @Скрыто отформатируйте пожалуйста код и поправьте заголовок вопроса на что-нибудь более нормальное

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dtNbe/ - без javascript

Comment: Зачем прибегать к использованию **JS**, если есть специальный тег **[lable][1]**?


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/html/label

Comment: @HA3IK, с lable можно если их немного. А есть их 1000? Много айдишников - не есть хорошо. Поэтому JS - более универсально.

Comment: @FlamesoFF не всегда для label нужны id

    <label><div>Label</div><input type="text"/></label>

вполне правильная конструкция.

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/dtNbe/1/

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" /> 
<div></div>
```

css:

```
div{
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

js:

```
$('div').on('click', function(){
    $('input').focus();
});
```

[Пример.](http://jsfiddle.net/fJzs2/2/)