# При нажатии ставить focus в input

Tags: jquery

> ```
>     Есть код голосового поиска, как сделать чтоб при нажатии на микрофон ставился фокус в input#story
> ```

```
function startDictation() {
      if($('#story').val().length>3) $('#story').change();
       if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {
        let recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        let story = document.getElementById('story');
        recognition.continuous = false;
        recognition.interimResults = true;
        recognition.lang = "ru-RU";
        recognition.start();
        recognition.onresult = function(e) {
          story.value = e.results[0][0].transcript;
          story.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
          let a = $('#story').val();
          0 == a.length ? $("#searchsuggestions").fadeOut() : dle_search_value != a && a.length >= (clearInterval(dle_search_delay), dle_search_delay = setInterval(function() {
            dle_do_search(a)
          }, 600))
        };
      }
    }

<i title="Скажите" onclick="startDictation()" class="fa fa-microphone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Возможно дубликат вопроса - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/301819/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-input

Answer (score 0):

М? Или можешь эту строку пихать куда угодно под свои ифы))

```
function startDictation() {

      $('#story').focus();

      if($('#story').val().length>3) $('#story').change();
       if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {
        let recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        let story = document.getElementById('story');
        recognition.continuous = false;
        recognition.interimResults = true;
        recognition.lang = "ru-RU";
        recognition.start();
        recognition.onresult = function(e) {
          story.value = e.results[0][0].transcript;
          story.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
          let a = $('#story').val();
          0 == a.length ? $("#searchsuggestions").fadeOut() : dle_search_value != a && a.length >= (clearInterval(dle_search_delay), dle_search_delay = setInterval(function() {
            dle_do_search(a)
          }, 600))
        };
      }
    }

<i title="Скажите" onclick="startDictation()" class="fa fa-microphone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```